# Why do I get reading numeric values as string in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

I try to read excel file using NPOI library.

Here is the code:

```
  public void ReadDataFromXL()
        {
            try
            {                
                for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
                {
                    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        var columnIndex = row.GetCell(j).ColumnIndex;
                        var cell = row.GetCell(j);

                        if (cell != null)
                        {
                            switch (cell.CellType)
                            {
                                case CellType.Numeric:
                                    var val = cell.NumericCellValue; ;

                                    break;
                                case CellType.String:
                                    var str = cell.StringCellValue;

                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here the content of .xlsx file that I try to read:

[image]

As you can see column X and column Y are numeric columns.
But when I start to read this columns using the code above some of the numeric values in X and Y column have been recognizes by code as string values.

For example in picture above the cell **B4** is numeric type but, on `cell.CellType` it shows `String` and the value of the string is `31.724732480727\n`. '\n' is appended to the value.

Any idea why some numeric values appeared as `string` and why '\n' appended to the value?

Comment: `\n` is a newline. Was the number copy/pasted in from somewhere, or entered manually?

Comment: if you just read the data from excel, you maybe want to use the OleDbConnection class.

Comment: @dognotdog it was red from file.The file was serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the datatype of the column is of String, so if you wanted to check for the double datatype (assuming its going to be in the `num+'\n'` format, you could try the following snippet of code.

```
        String number = "1512421.512\n";
        double res;
        if (double.TryParse(number.Substring(0, number.Length - 1), out res))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a number! " + res);
        }
```

Comment: But want to understand where from it comes - '\n'

Comment: Where does this data come from? Chances are, it may have come from a spreadsheet where the data was copy/pasted in, which would explain the newline.

Comment: ok , but why NPOI library relates it (the new line)  as part of of data?

Comment: Because whoever copied and pasted the data also copied the newline character.

Comment: ok tnx.I removed the 'new line'  from cell and it works perfect.